# How to set the field2 and field3 to required based on the field1 value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, rsuite

```
 Schema.model({
    field1: StringType(),
    field2: StringType(),
    field3: StringType()
    })

return (
 <Form
            model={model}
          >
<FormControl name="field1" />
<FormControl name="field2" />
<FormControl name="field3" />
</Form>
)
```

How to set the `field2` and `field3` to required field?

What I'm trying to do is when `field` is equal to `jake` the `field2` and `field3` will be required. but when its not equal to `jake` then its not required.

I tried to use the `onChange` on the `field1` but it doesn't work.
also I tried the `addRule` in `field2` & `field3` but it doesn't work also.

```
addRule((value, data) => { 
 if (data.field1 ==='jake') {
 return true;
} return false;
}
```

I want to apply this in field2 and field3 `StringType().isRequired('Required field')` when the value in field1 is jake.

Answer (score 0):

Add rule looks correct to me, but if it's not working, maybe try this in you JSX:

```
  {this.state.field1 === 'jake'?
        <FormControl name="field2" required/>
        <FormControl name="field3" required/>
       :
       <FormControl name="field2" />
        <FormControl name="field3" />
```

and for field on
`onChange={e => this.setState({field1: e.target.value})}`

Note: I am not sure if this would be the optimal way, but it should work.

Comment: yes it display the error but when I try to remove the value jake on field1 then on the field2 when I try to input some value it still display the required message

Comment: Then try using a function instead, that returns the input fields with the required attribute `if this.state.field === 'jake'` or the input fields without the required attribute in the else block and use it with the onChange event for the field1, and render the function in the JSX like so `{requiredOrNot}`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with the render cycle. How, exactly, did you implement changing the required attribute on change? You need to do it through a state variable so that react knows to re-render when it changes.

Comment: it works when I use the state, but my issue now is how do I display the error message cause before I used like this. StringType().isRequired();